# How to do Json query in ansible with matched value

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, json-query

Can someone tell me if it is possible to do?
I have the following list

```
list:
  - dev
  - uat
```

I want to iterate through the above list and grab the value of respective `IpAddress` from the below output.

```
{
    "Tags": [
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dh7435490fjksfd", 
            "Environment": "production", 
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.8"
        }, 
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dh7435dsj89jfe", 
            "Environment": "dev", 
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.3"
        },
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dsdj456ovfvfd", 
            "Environment": "uat", 
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.7"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the output I am looking for

```
[
 "10.0.0.3",
 "10.0.0.7"
]
```

I am trying with  this filter `Tags| json_query('[*].IpAddress')`. But it gives me all `IpAddress` from the list.

Comment: I'm afraid *json_query* test `contains` won't work here. Try `selectattr` and `map(attribute='IpAddress'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_list: [dev, uat]
    my_Tags: [
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dh7435490fjksfd", 
            "Environment": "production", 
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.8"
        }, 
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dh7435dsj89jfe", 
            "Environment": "dev", 
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.3"
        },
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance", 
            "ResourceId": "i-8dsdj456ovfvfd", 
            "Environment": "uat", 
            "IpAddress": "10.0.0.7"
        }
    ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_Tags|selectattr('Environment', 'in', my_list)|
                 map(attribute='IpAddress')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - 10.0.0.3
  - 10.0.0.7
```

Comment: awesome. Thank You, You are my hero :)